# Android Gstreamer Playing in background

Tags: android, gstreamer

I am developing an Audio Streaming Application using Gstreamer Library it work perfectly but when the Application goes in background the Streaming stops, So i wanted to know is Gstreamer support audio streaming in background.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem by removing nativeSurfaceFinalize(); from surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) method.